# Error Closing a Form Through a User Control

Tags: vb.net-2010

In the program I'm writing, there is just one form. I've made a user control visible and it contains several buttons. One of the buttons is supposed to close the form when clicked.  I can't find any way to do this without getting the error: "Cannot access a disposed object. Object name: 'ShapeContainer.'" I'm pretty sure I understand the problem; after the form has been closed, the user control no longer exists, so there's an error when `Form.Close()` (I've tried `Form.Dispose()` too) has completed and it tries to go back to the code inside the button click event. Does anyone know how I could accomplish closing the form through this user control's button without getting the error?

Answer (score 0):

Okay I'm pretty new to vb but I think if you get rid of the `Form.Dispose()` & `Form.Close` then try `Me.Close()` as you are referring to the current Form that the button control is located on.

You Should have got this error:
(`Error 1   'NameSpace_.Form1' cannot refer to itself through its default instance; use 'Me' instead.`)